# How to I write a grib object to a grib file?

Tags: python-xarray, grib

I have a grib object directly in my temps after importing it from Copernicus. Now I need to save it as a grib file.
Could you please tell me how ? Knowing that to_grib is a function used to write xarray to grib file.
Thanks a lot for your answers.